# Developer specific REST Api endpoints with separation of service code

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have 4 different services that are running in 4 different aws accounts. Each service has their own rest api endpoints, service dependencies, database, etc. Whenever a developer tries to deploy his code to one of the services, other developers are getting blocked currently. Because when the other developer deploy his code, the previous developer's changes are getting overwritten. Our services run as docker instances inside EC2.

How to mitigate this situation? Is it possible to create/launch a person specific service with a configured public endpoint?

Eg: The below is my expectation. Let's say two developers are there, dev1 and dev2. Dev1 deploys his code for service1 into an ec2 instance and Dev2 deploys his code for the same service1 into the same ec2 instance. Both of their service code should run separately but the underlying database and other dependencies should be the same. So when a tester, tests the service, they can test each developer's code by just hitting each developer specific endpoints.

eg: https://dev1.com/docall and https://dev2.com/docall

I know the above requirement is little vague. Please let me know if the ask is not very clear. Just need some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have a pre-production environment you can use for testing?  And hopefully you have ways of doing at least some level of testing on your services without actually deploying them, and a way to create test environments?

Comment: yeah we have a preproduction environment. The thing is, more than one feature gets developed at a time and we need to test both the features at the same time in the same environment, by creating or having different endpoints

Answer (score 0):

The overwritten issue is very strange. Sounds like your workflow is wrong. Sounds like all developers are pushing right into live branch, and/or not solving the conflicts and accepting just their changes.

If it is the issue I suggest the following workflow:

I assume that you are using GitHub as VCS. In that case, you should better have a master branch that is live and "well-tested". and you are taking a copy from that let's call it dev-branch and building all new features on that. Until you decide to take it to live. And all development should happen in an individual branch which is a copy of the dev-branch itself. you make your changes in that individual branch. once the feature is done (since it was a while) then you take the latest dev into your individual branch, solve any conflicts open a pull request to the dev-branch. then if wanted to live.

More details and chart is here :https://lucamezzalira.com/2014/03/10/git-flow-vs-github-flow/

Comment: The issue is not associated with production or live environment. It's more associated with testing on lower environment. The main issue is, when a developer pushes his branch on to a EC2 instance on a AWS account, a particular service on that account is basically locked by him. Unless he finishes his work, other developers cannot push their change into that EC2 instance.